# How to search for a specific string on a list from a dictionary and return all element that contain that string in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My dictionaries have this structure:

```
{"_id":"name","tweets:[tweet1, tweet2, tweet,3]}
```

I need to do a query that returns the tweets that have a specific string. Imagine tweet2 contains the string "hello", and I want all the tweets from every other dictionary with that string.

I've been using the following query to do so but it hasn't given me the right results:

```
db.collection.find({"tweets":{{$elemMatch:{$regex:".*hello*."}}})
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it as below:

```
db.collections.find({tweets: {$regex: new RegExp('^.*' + "tweet2" + '.*', 'i')}}, {tweets: {$elemMatch: {$regex: new RegExp('^.*' + "tweet2" + '.*', 'i')}}})
```

But **$elemMatch**  projection operator provides another way to alter the returned document to contain only the first matched tweets element.

You can also get same output by positional($) operator as well.

If you need filter an array during projection, which including all matches, instead of just the first one for that you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation operator.

Hope it will works